# Crashlystics not reporting crashes - Carthage Swift

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I'm using latest Crashlytics Version 3.12.0 (136)

**What's working**:
I have Retention data and It's fetching all that almost instantly.
But what's not working is crash reporting.

**How I've done:**
I'm using **Carthage** dependency manager.
This is how I added it in Cartfile:

```
binary "https://building42.github.io/Specs/Carthage/iOS/Fabric.json"
binary "https://building42.github.io/Specs/Carthage/iOS/Answers.json"
binary "https://building42.github.io/Specs/Carthage/iOS/Crashlytics.json"
```

I've configured Xcode project with Fabrics app. dropped Crashlystics and Fabrics framework thru `Linked Frameworks and libraries` in Xcode.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried uploading DSYMs multiple ways. I downloaded from App Store Connect, zipped from xarchive.
Nothing seems to be working.

**Debug Information Format** is set to `DWARF with dSYM file.`

**I've tried force test with:**

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

And with a corrupt `performSegue`.

What could I be missing? any help would be much appreciated.
**PS:** Think once before you mark it duplicate.

Comment: Update: Just removed everything and added again solved the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this crashlytics tutorial on fabric.io](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) could help you.

In summary, the following things should be configured.

- Install necessary libraries.
- Configure `Run Script`, let it upload `dSYM symbol` file after app binary built.
- Configure your `API Key` from `fabric.io` to your project, in `Info.plist` file.
- Last step, call `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Or, [install a Mac app made by fabric.io team](https://fabric.io/downloads/xcode). It will guide you step by step. 
My first project with crashlytics was configured by this tool.

#### UPDATE:

I create a new single view application, and install libraries with `CocoaPod`. Then configure the project step by step [with Mac app tool](https://fabric.io/downloads/xcode).

When I configure `Run Script`, it doesn't work. Until I change `Debug Information Format` for `Debug` to `DWARF with dSYM File`. It's `DWARF` by default.

[image]

And then, go through the fabric's Mac app step by step, and trigger `Crash` by `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`. Then, I got the following crash report.

[image]

### Codes

A new single view project.

```
//## AppDelegate.swift


import UIKit
import Fabric
import Crashlytics

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

        return true
    }
}

//## ViewController.swift 
//## Put a button in center, with `@IBAction` when clicked.

@IBAction func OnBtnTest(_ sender: Any) {

    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
}
```

Comment: I create a new project and test it. The Mac app tool is very helpful.

Comment: I have retention data working but not the crash report. Issue is when you use with carthage. Implementation with cocoapod is not related.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see unsymbolicated crashes on fabric? If yes, then try uploading the `.DSYM` file for of that particular build. Fabric does symbolicate the crash logs sometimes if you enable the `bitcode`.

Comment: I've tried uploading, it seems like there's some issue with Carthage installation? Not entirely sure what's happening.